# How to select multiple Checkbox and create an Array with the values in android

Tags: android, arrays, checkbox

> I have added 9 `CheckBox` in my `Fragment` which is getting checked
>   according to the response from JSON. If user wants to update his/her
>   profile, He/she can `check/uncheck` any of them. Now I have to confirm
>   that how many of them are `checked`  and create an `Array` as a
>   `parameter` according to that. I am not using any `adapter` for that.
>   please let know how to set the condition to get the value of only
>   checked checkboxes

I am trying to do like this

```
cb_prfl_setng_general=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_general);
    cb_prfl_setng_economics = (CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_economics);
    cb_prfl_setng_business=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_business);
    cb_prfl_setng_social=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_social);
    cb_prfl_setng_politics=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_politics);
    cb_prfl_setng_entertainmnt=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_entertainmnt);
    cb_prfl_setng_technology=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_technology);
    cb_prfl_setng_spritual=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_spritual);
    cb_prfl_setng_sports=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.cb_prfl_setng_sports);



     if(cb_prfl_setng_general.isChecked()){

                String[] Interest = {"catagory_id=1"};

            }else if(cb_prfl_setng_economics.isChecked()){

                String[] Interest = {"catagory_id=1","catagory_id=2"};

            }else if(cb_prfl_setng_general.isChecked()){

                String[] Interest = {"catagory_id=1","catagory_id=2","catagory_id=3"};

            }else if(cb_prfl_setng_entertainmnt.isChecked()){

                String[] Interest = {"catagory_id=1","catagory_id=2","catagory_id=3","catagory_id=4"};
            }
```

But I don't think this is the right way to get the exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test each checkbox separately and accumulate the category ids:

```
    List<String> interestList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // for each checkbox checked, accumulate a category id in the list
    if (cb_prfl_setng_general.isChecked()) {
        interestList.add("catagory_id=1");
    }

    if (cb_prfl_setng_economics.isChecked()) {
        interestList.add("catagory_id=2");
    }

    if (cb_prfl_setng_general.isChecked()) {
        interestList.add("catagory_id=3");
    }

    if (cb_prfl_setng_entertainmnt.isChecked()) {
        interestList.add("catagory_id=4");
    }

    .
    .
    .

    // convert the list into an array
    String[] interest = interestList.toArray(new String[interestList.size()]);

    System.out.println("interest");
    for (String str : interest) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

Comment: No, I don't want to know that when user checks/unchecks a checkbox, I just want to know that final value at the time of page submission click. like: 'Savebutton.setonclicklistener(this)' . at this point I have to get the value that is checkbox is checked/unchecked and create an String array with the respective values.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are asking.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Kris for your answer, But kris when I am trying to print that value "System.out.println("interest"+interest);"    I am getting this print in Log "interest[Ljava.lang.String;@417232e0" . Is it fine???

Comment: Arrays don't have a `toString()` that will print the whole array.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

String WeekDays="";
List DayList = new ArrayList();

```
if (cbSunday.isChecked()) {
                DayList.add(String.valueOf(cbSunday.getText()));
            }
            if (cbMonday.isChecked()) {
                DayList.add(String.valueOf(cbMonday.getText()));
            }
            if (cbTuesday.isChecked()) {
                DayList.add(String.valueOf(cbTuesday.getText()));
            }
            if (cbWednesday.isChecked()) {
                DayList.add(String.valueOf(cbWednesday.getText()));
            }
            if (cbThursday.isChecked()) {
                DayList.add(String.valueOf(cbThursday.getText()));
            }
            if (cbFriday.isChecked()) {
                DayList.add(String.valueOf(cbFriday.getText()));
            }
            if (cbSaturday.isChecked()) {
                DayList.add(String.valueOf(cbSaturday.getText()));
            }


            String[] Days = DayList.toArray(new String[DayList.size()]);

            WeekDays="";

            for (String str : Days) {
                if(WeekDays.equals(""))
                {
                    WeekDays=WeekDays+str;
                }
                else {

                    WeekDays = WeekDays + "," + str;
                }

                WeekDays=WeekDays;                   
                 Log.d("LogDays",WeekDays);
                 
            }
```